# Apps that use IAP to purchase items must assign the correct Purchasability type issue in IN-App Purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

```
    **My application was rejected due to Product Purchasability type. In our scenario, User purchased image and download into his/her device.We want to do product is only available for user single device. We want to keep Purchasability type Consumable. Right now we were getting following rejection issue. Please let us know how we can Keep Purchasability type Consumable?**
```

***11.7: Apps that use IAP to purchase items must assign the correct Purchasability type***

```
  Also, we found that the Purchasability Type for one or more of your In App Purchase products was inappropriately set, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

   However, based on product functionality, it would be more appropriate to use the Non-Consumable In App Purchase type. Non-consumable products are only purchased once by users and are always available on all devices that are associated with that user's iTunes account. 

    For more information about Purchasability Type, please to refer to the In-App Purchase Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect.  

  The Purchasability type cannot be changed once an In App Purchase product has been created. Therefore, you will need to create a new In App Purchase product with the correct Purchasability Type. To create a new In App Purchase in iTunes Connect, go to Manage Your In App Purchases, select your app, and click "Create New". The current product will show in iTunes Connect as "Rejected".For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support.
```

When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:
 - complete details of your rejection issue(s) 
- screenshots - steps to reproduce the issue(s)
 - symbolicated crash logs 
- if your issue results in a crash log  If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue,

please try testing the workflow as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce a crash or bug that only App Review or users are seeing. Note: Apps that offer In-App Purchase products that must be restorable are required to include a "Restore" feature. The following In-App Purchase types must be restorable: 
- non-consumable products 
- auto-renewing subscriptions 
- free subscriptions For more information, please see the section, Restoring Transactions, in the In-App Purchase Programming Guide.

Comment: I am also having same problem, did you find any solution means kindly share me. Thanks

Comment: As per apple guidelines into check your product in which category? In my case we have sell image/Poster/Banner.That all are digital contests.So, It Must be Non-Consumable Type.

Comment: Yes, I am using Image posting. I am having two plans such as 1]auto - renewing 2]Consumable. (1) is used for limited posting plans and (2) is used for unlimited plans.
In this scenario whether i need to use a Consumable or non-consumable

Comment: @dineshprasanna,Image is a digital content.So, It's Must be in Non-Consumable category.So change your product category with appropriate functionality.No other way.If you need more help then feel free contact on me my email id.

Comment: Could you provide the email id, i will explain through mail

Comment: dadhaniya.renish@gmail.com OR Check my Profile

Comment: Thanks, Please check the mail and provide feedback